# Are you allowed to set the ball over the net sideways instead of forwards/backwards in indoor volleyball?

Tags: rules, volleyball

I looked through the [indoor volleyball rulebook](http://www.fivb.org/EN/Refereeing-Rules/documents/FIVB-Volleyball_Rules_2017-2020-EN-v06.pdf), and can't find anything on this in there, through Google, nor in any previously asked questions here.

I was told many times before that you cannot purposely set a ball over the net unless your back or front are parallel to the net, as in you can only set it forward or backwards, not to the side. However, I was watching some indoor volleyball highlights and a girl did a purposeful low side set over the net for a point.

What is the official rule? I'm referring to indoor volleyball (recreational/intermediate leagues, not like college or anything) and I would like to know the official ruling.

Edit: to be clear, in case it matters, I'm referring specifically to the 2nd hit.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, you are allowed to set the ball over the net *anyway* you want.

> I was told many times before that you cannot purposely set a ball over the net unless your back or front are parallel to the net

I think the person who told you so, was referring to Beach-volleyball.
It matches the [FIVB-Beach rule 13.2.5](https://www.fivb.org/EN/Refereeing-Rules/Documents/FIVB-BeachVolleyball_Rules_2017-2020-EN-v05.pdf)

N.B. : As a back row setter, you cannot block, attack, set or hit the ball at all **above the net**.